# next-auth TypeScript All declarations of 'NEXTAUTH_URL' must have identical modifiers

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-example I'm going to use next-auth in my app that uses type scripts by referring to this address
In my app, I'm adding files by copying and pasting environmental variables on that homepage, and in the process.ts file

All declarations of 'NEXTAUTH_URL' must have identical modifiers.
and 'process.ts' cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file. Add an import, export, or an empty 'export {}' statement to make it a module.
I get this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CiSi.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSr9G.png)

The phrase NEXTAUTH_URL is only in the .env.local file and it looks like a picture, so what's the problem? How should I fix it?

I'm going to modify the package.json file
I also tried to remove the next-auth phrase in the env file, but I couldn't find it anywhere else

Comment: Hi there , please share the error message as a plain text format :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.